# How to place the picture in front of first figure

Tags: graphics

I have letterhead in PDF file, but no logo (the filename is coba.pdf)

[image]

Now, I want to add logo in letterhead on latex.

First, I use `\includegraphics` to show the letterhead.

Second, I want to show the logo using `\includegraphics` too, but I don't know how to place the logo in the front of letterhead file and placed in left of the text.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{letter}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, bottom=1.50cm, top=1.50cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \hspace*{-0.8cm}
    \includegraphics{coba.pdf}
\end{document}
```

If I place the logo as my code above, the result is

[image]

I want the logo is placed in front of letterhead file, and placed in the left of the text as below.

[image]

Anyone know how to make the code to produce as I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
\hbox{\rlap{\includegraphic{head}}\raise2ex\rlap{\includegraphic{logo}}}
```

Set appropiate dimesion of logo and the dimesion of `\raise`. The `2ex` is only example here because I don't see how the logo looks like.

Comment: Okay,, I have tried your code and its works. I have set the dimension of `\raise` based on my logo. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: But, I use`\includegraphics` instead of `\includegraphic`.